# React don't remember firebase state Error this.setState is not a function

Tags: reactjs

This is the issue I'm facing right now, previuously in a single page web app I was able to access `firebase.auth()` anywhere, right now evertytime I try using config I got undefined and I don't know if user is logged in or not. Please someone assist, the code above is 100% working, the issue is with `show()` function

```
import fire from '../../../config/Fire';


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.signup = this.signup.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      loading: false,
      fullname: '',
    };
  }

  login(e) {
    this.setState({ loading:true });
    e.preventDefault();
    fire.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then((u)=>{
      this.setState({ loading:false });

    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });

  }

  show() {
    const { currentUser } = fire.auth();
    this.setState({ fullname: currentUser.displayName })
  }

...

<Button onClick={this.show} color="dark" className="px-4">Show</Button>

<h2 className="mb-5">{this.state.fullname}</h2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this.setState isn't working in show function because you are not binding show function. You need to bind show function in constructor like

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.login = this.login.bind(this);
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
this.signup = this.signup.bind(this);
this.show = this.show.bind(this);
this.state = {
  email: '',
  password: '',
  loading: false,
  fullname: '',
};
}

show() {
   const { currentUser } = fire.auth();
   this.setState({ fullname: {currentUser ? currentUser.displayName: ""} })
 }
```

If you don't want to do binding manually then use arrow function like

```
show = () => {
  const { currentUser } = fire.auth();
  this.setState({ fullname: currentUser ? currentUser.displayName: "" })
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks,I understand that binding thing, it's actually working but not solving my issue, the react app cannot remember the state when reloading the page, I got  Cannot read property 'displayName' of null, Do you want me to edit the question?

Comment: @blvckasvp No not required check my updated answer for your second issue

Comment: Unexpected token  :( I understand what you tried to do but I guess the state is no longer there, I fixed it by removing brackets but still as I said no state, I'll post another question, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies on the Firebase functions which takes time to retrieve or search from the Firebase

Now while it's doing that, the state in which the Firebase function was called is already gone. While you call `this.state` in the Firebase function, it is referencing the current updated state, rather it should call the old one in which the Firebase function was called.

Found out through writing multiple `console.log` statements EVERYWHERE!!!

Suppose we have a function like so

```
show = () =>{
    console.log("1"); 

    firebase.anyFirebaseFunction({
        console.log("2"); 
    });

    console.log("3");
}
```

Now normally the output would be

```
123
```

but due to the Firebase function call it will be...

```
132
```

so get a reference to the original state and `setState` through that reference.
Tried using all kinds of bind but didn't work. So try it like so...

```
login(e) {
    //Get the state reference here
    let oldstate=this;

    this.setState({ loading:true });
    e.preventDefault();
    fire.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then((u)=>{
          //use it like this
          oldstate.setState({ loading:false });
        //this.setState({ loading:false });

    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });

  }

  show() {
    const { currentUser } = fire.auth();
    this.setState({ fullname: currentUser.displayName })
  }
```

That is also the reason your `.auth()` is storing `null` in `currentUser`, the sign in hasn't completed yet and the `.auth()` function is called beforehand.